# Message function not sending all required data

Tags: php

I have a website I'm trying to build for our workers in the field to be able to submit part requests.

I have all products selected by our Welders sent to a checkout page with a small form with job info ect. that needs to be sent along with all the part info to our order desk to then ship it to them.

It is sending the email but the problem is that it is only sending the name of the person and the subject but not any of the parts that they selected. So I'm trying to figure out how to send all the data on the checkout page through email.

Here is the Function that is sending the message:

```
    function send_message_admin(){
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $to               = "*******@yahoo.com";
            $from_name        = $_POST['name'];
            $cart             = $_POST['cart'];
            $subject          = "Welder Order";
            $job_number       = $_POST['job_number'];
            $box_color        = $_POST['box_color'];
            $shipping         = $_POST['shipping'];

            $headers = "From: {$from_name} {$job_number}";

            $result = mail($to,$subject , $cart, $headers);       
            if (!$result) {
                set_message("We could not send your email.");
                redirect("info.php");
            } else {
                set_message("your message has been sent");
                redirect("info.php");
            }
        }
    }
```

and here is the checkout page:

```
<?php require_once("../resources/config.php"); ?>
<?php include (TEMPLATE_FRONT . DS. "header.php"); ?>




    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">


<!-- /.row -->

<div class="row">
<h4 class="text-center bg-danger"></h4>
      <h1>Checkout</h1>
      <h2 class="text-center"><?php display_message(); ?></h2>
  <form name="cart" action="info.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="********@yahoo.com">
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="US">

    <table  class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
           <th>Product</th>

           <th>Quantity</th>


          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <?php cart(); ?>
        </tbody>

    </table>



<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <h2 class="section-heading">Job Info</h2>
            <h3 class="section-subheading ">
            <?php display_message(); ?></h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">

              <?php  send_message_admin(); ?>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name " id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="number" name="job_number"class="form-control" placeholder="Job Number " id="email">
                            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="box_color">Box Color:</label>
                          <select name="box_color">
                          <label for="shipping">Box Color:</label>
                          <option value=""></option>
                          <option value="RED">RED</option>
                          <option value="GREEN">GREEN</option>
                          <option value="BLUE">BLUE</option>
                          <option value="YELLOW">YELLOW</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="shipping">Shipping Instructions:</label>
                          <select name="shipping">
                          <option value="RED"></option>
                          <option value="RED">1:URGENT</option>
                          <option value="GREEN">2:Semi-urgent</option>
                          <option value="BLUE">3:Not Urgent</option>
                          <option value="YELLOW">4:Priority</option>
                          <option value="YELLOW">5:Low priority</option>
                          <option value="rep_deliver">Rep Delivery</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                        <div id="success"></div>
                        <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-xl">Send Order</button>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

```
 </div><!--Main Content-->


    </div>
</div>
</form>
    <!-- /.container -->
<?php include (TEMPLATE_FRONT. DS. "footer.php"); ?>
```

Comment: send $cart = $_POST instead of $cart = $_POST['cart'];

Comment: Tried that but no luck. Made my mail function completely break down.

Answer (score 0):

I see the first issue as you html has two `</form>` in it.
The html form end block should end as

```
                            <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-xl">Send Order</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply and help. I changed the code but it was no help with the issue unfortunately.

Comment: @Gandalf_da_tall could you please update the question with the new html